# Does the civil industry use the CAN FD bus?

Tags: commercial-aviation, avionics, arinc-429

Does anyone know if commercial aircraft are using the CAN FD communication bus?

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I would say the answer is no for the following reasons:

1. In all my years in the avionics industry, I've never heard of anyone
   even discussing the possibility (though I realize CAN FD is fairly
   recent).
2. There are numerous manufacturers that use ARINC 825 which is an
   adaptation of the basic CAN.
3. The [AEEC](https://www.aviation-ia.com/activities/aeec) has no
   active committee working to update ARINC 825 to include support for
   CAN FD which would be the normal process before it would be used in
   avionics.

Avionics suppliers just can't decide to use a new databus.  Their equipment has to talk to equipment from other manufacturers and if you don't have a defined protocol and agreement between suppliers it just won't work.

Comment: ARINC 825 2018 Supplement 4 describes supported extensions for capabilities derived from CAN FD such as increased data rates (up to 4mbps) and 64byte payload sizes.